# How do I utilize OpenLayer (OpenStreetMap) tiles in my mapview iOS 7

Tags: ios, mkmapview, openlayers, mktileoverlay

I started researching maps recently and wanted to know how I could implement the tiles from OpenLayer (which is what I believe openstreetmap is displaying) over my MKMapView. The default sdk doesnt show enough detail for what I want to do. I could ping the servers for the tiles but I keep seeing warning about doing so. So my two problems are 1) how do i get the tiles from the openlayer and overlay them in my mapview and 2) is there a way of getting these tiles ahead of time and just storing them in my app? 
I am only trying to map a small area (roughly 9 square miles worth). Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a MKTileOverlay which overlays the tiles from OpenSteetMap.

There is some sample code for this by Mattt Thompson on NSHipster:

```
static NSString * const template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";

MKTileOverlay *overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
overlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;

[self.mapView addOverlay:overlay
               level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

For each required tile, this will download the data from the URL template.

See http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/ (where this is taken from) for more details.

If you want to manage your own tile cache (for example, some tiles are shipped along with the application), you can subclass

```
- (void)loadTileAtPath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path result:(void (^)(NSData *tileData, NSError *error))result
```

and provide the data directly.
However, I'd imagine that even 9 square miles worth of data would be very large if all zoom levels are required. You could potentially have a hybrid though, and provide some data with your app, and the higher zoom levels are downloaded directly.

Comment: This is what I currently have but I dont want to keep downloading from their servers (dont want to get blocked). Hybrid wouldn't be too bad either. I had a problem trying to figure out what the x and y of the url would be if i wanted to manually download them. Is there a way to calculate or visually calibrate an area and download tiles at that particular zoom?

Comment: Define very large. WMTS tiles are usually only a few kilobytes in size, and 9 sq miles is a very small area.

Comment: You've probably figured this out by now, but this page tells you how to download OSM tiles: http://shiki.me/blog/offline-maps-in-ios-using-openstreetmap-and-route-me/